# How to delete Kubernetes Job object in Java via io.fabric8

Tags: java, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, fabric8, kubernetes-jobs

I am using kubernetes io.fabric8 client to manage my Kubernetes Jobs.

Using batch v1 apis kubernetesClient.batch().v1().jobs().inNamespace(namespace)

I am not able to find a way to delete the Job by its name.

Answer (score 2):

Found it

```
client.batch().v1().jobs().inNamespace(namespace).resource(job).delete();
```